# How can I use ".attr('disabled', false)" to btn[0]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
let btn = $("#btns").find(".btn-type03");

btn.attr('disabled', false); // Working

btn[0].attr('disabled', false); // Not Working
```

How can I use `.attr('disabled', false)` to `btn[0]`?
What do I have to do at `btn[0]`?

I don't want "btn[0].disabled = true"

Comment: _why_ are you specifically wanting to do `btn[0].attr()` if `btn.attr()` is working? `.attr()` is a jquery function (https://api.jquery.com/attr/) which operates on a jquery element, while `.setAttribute()` is a native JS function that operates on a nativs JS _Element_ (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: try `$(btn[0]).attr('disabled', false);`

Comment: use prop(), not attr(). attr() works because it's smart about handling boolean attribs.

Comment: `find(".btn-type03");` return an array/set of HTML element objects, `attr()` is jQuery instance method. To make it works, you can write `$("#btns").find(".btn-type03").first().attr('disabled', false)`. See the documentation https://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: `btn.eq(0).prop("disabled", false)` is what you want. See https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: @dandavis should that be:  attr() works because it's smart about handling boolean properties  ?

Comment: attr() is not smart about properties, unless there's an alias. `false` as a 2nd arg to attr() removes the attrib, whereas `false` to prop() sets the loose-typed value of the property to `false`.